# Where do we draw the line for "racially charged" terms?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

Recently, [I've been informed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-do-i-reference-a-racially-charged-term-without-it-getting-deleted-as-a-raci) that under no circumstances is it *ever* permissible to use "racial slurs" other than to clarify what I'm asking about in questions about racial slurs, and ideally not then.

I don't disagree with that point. I'll admit that in composing the (now deleted) question that inspired that meta question I didn't consider that a word that hasn't been commonly heard in nearly half a century could still be hurtful and insulting.

However: we still accept use of words that carry a similar connotation in reference to a fantasy race.  Wizards of the Coast recently changed their game rules to recognize that assuming that a goblin, orc, kobold, etc. is inherently evil might be indirectly hurtful to those who have suffered racism for their real ancestry, or discrimination of other kinds.

Do we have plans to similarly update, or will we still consider "orc" as racially evil or a generic enemy-without-reason to be an acceptable usage?

Comment: I just want you to be aware that, despite saying you *won't* argue the point, your use of "a term that has fallen out of use nearly a lifetime ago for its alternative connotation." and "a term not commonly used outside children's games and Hollywood scripts since before most or all users were born" come across as arguing that very point. They come across sort of like "How was I to know?" or "Really? Even words like *this* can't be used?" I'm sure that wasn't your intention, but it comes across poorly

Comment: @ThomasMarkov and Zeiss I'm going to jump in here before things continue to roll down hill. If you think this should be duped, the close vote menu is a short scroll up that way, there's no reason to argue about it here in the comments (at least not with this line of reasoning).

Comment: @ZeissIkon You seem to be super misunderstanding the issues of orcs in games. The terms “orc” and “goblin” aren't a racial slur for anything, but that isn't the issue. The issue is with the nature and portrayal of orcs in fantasy narratives, in how they embody real-world prejudices against real-world people, and in how we're made to interact with them, as explained well by NK Jemisin in [The Unbearable Baggage of Orcing](http://nkjemisin.com/2013/02/from-the-mailbag-the-unbearable-baggage-of-orcing/). That's a serious issue worth discussing, but it's something separate from racial slurs.

Comment: And apparently, judging by the votes, this is a question I'm not even supposed to ask, or even after the edit (which is when the majority of the downvotes came in) it's still badly asked (and I don't see any hints as to how, if that's the case).  Pardon me if I risk getting blocked, but I'm going to delete this question later in the day if I don't hear a good reason not to.

Comment: The good reason not to is to provide an opportunity for everyone, including you, to learn something about racism and how to grow and change.

Comment: @NautArch So if it's such an important question "So say we all" then why are the votes running so heavily against?  Yeah, I know, unanswerable.  None the less, it doesn't make one feel "welcome to ask" for questions on sensitive issues.  Rather, it makes me feel like "I should know better than to ask, or need to ask, or..."

Comment: While the downvotes may be upsetting, please look at this as an opportunity for yourself to learn and grow. Both the answers and doppelgreener's comments provide a lot of good things to consider.

Comment: Personal growth is a personal choice. But please look at this as an opportunity to learn and not another time where one doubles-down and entrenches themselves in previous beliefs.

Comment: Serious suggestion, though -- if we're going to agree to give words the power to control what we're allowed to say and ask, perhaps the pre-check should flag those words with a message like "Are you sure you want to use XXXX?  Some may find it offensive, leading to downvotes, closure, or deletion."

Comment: Or, we can just be more aware of when to use words and in what context we are trying to use them. I'm very much trying to maintain that you are asking this in good faith, but I do hope you are asking these questions as a means to learn and change and not as something else.

Comment: I'm trying to improve everyone's experience.  I'm suggesting a basic design idea: "put the knowledge in the world, not in the user."  Some, like me two days ago, might not realize that offensive terms *don't become obsolete*, or even that words they use in innocence are offensive (no, I'm not claiming that last for myself).

Comment: I downvoted the question because I was concerned you were using a serious issue  about racial sensitivity to angle for justifying that you should be allowed to use “Injuns”, which is inappropriate and insensitive, as well as totally misunderstanding the issue. If you think calling people “Injuns” is comparable to describing orcs as orcs, nazis as nazis, and the barbarian class as barbarians, then you need to re-assess these issues. You were asked not to use a slur and initially given the benefit of the doubt; it's your choice to build a mountain out of this molehill.

Comment: You say, "I'm trying to improve everyone's experience", yet you seem to be the only one put off by this experience. We have over [40,000 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) and nearly [100,000 answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) on the main site that have managed just fine without using racial slurs. There is nothing that needs improving.

Comment: "There is nothing that needs improving."  This isn't quite *hubris*, but it's some kind of purblindness.  This site makes improvements all the time -- quite recently they added they pre-check when submitting a question.  But I guess it's not worth doing anything to improve the system when only one closeted racist uses the site, is it?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Maybe I'm not understanding your position, so I'll ask: are you saying that the user voting/editing system that currently handles this sort of thing *inadequate* for handling this sort of issue? There are practical obstacles to setting up some sort of automated question-word-choice-review, and so I wonder if, how, and why such a thing would be better than existing user review process. It seems to have worked in this particular case, but I may just be missing the improvements you're after.

Comment: I'm saying that the user voting/editing system can lead to *all of this*, where a word list review could *prevent* it.  If it's not practical to set that up, then it's not practical -- I haven't done any programming in years, and never at the webapp level.  I was just suggesting that perhaps replacing the rushes/straw/sawdust on the floor with asphalt tile might reduce the danger of fire in case someone drops a match that wasn't quite out.

Comment: @Upper_Case See above.  Also, that's partly my way of admitting that, on thought, I'm pretty sure I don't even *know* every single word in English that might offend someone -- but a list to check against can be updated via a Meta question with a list answer where people can add offensive words site users should avoid -- and automating the process avoids people not even knowing such a question exists, never mind remembering to check it for every question and every answer...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Maybe I'm too late to this particular case, but from what I can see "all of this" was a single, prompt, quiet edit which removed the word in question (I didn't see any rough comments, but maybe they were deleted), followed by a couple of modestly heated meta exchanges. I'm not as confident as you seem to be that a canonical list of words that shouldn't be used would lead to outcomes much different than this one, but I think I understand your position much better now. Thank you for your responses to my questions.

Answer (score 19):

### The line is that we don't use derogatory terms

Unless there is absolutely no other way to communicate the idea *and* it is absolutely essential to the post (and maybe not even then), just don't use derogatory terms to real life people/groups on this site.

We don't apply this same reasoning to fantasy terms (unless they cause harm to real people in some other way) as there are no fantasy beings around to be harmed by them.

Answer (score 15):

### When those "racially charged" terms implicate real humans

If we use the term "orc" to define the Tolkienesque fantasy race, that's fine. If we use the term "monkey" to refer to the real-world part of simiiformes that have tails, that's fine too. These terms are not offensive because a) orcs don't exist and b) monkeys aren't sentient (or, at least, not sentient enough to take offence at being called monkeys).

However, both [orc](http://nkjemisin.com/2013/02/from-the-mailbag-the-unbearable-baggage-of-orcing/) and [monkey](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-05-25/goodes-gutted-but-places-no-blame/4712772) can and have been applied to groups of humans as a racial slur, that's **not** fine.