# What should be done if a game term being asked about is a slur?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

I recently asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/209931/do-half-castes-preserve-their-caste-charms-if-they-exalt-as-another-type-of-exal?noredirect=1#comment577455_209931) about Exalted Second edition and while I found the answer I found out that the term 'Half-caste' used in the game was also a slur. (I do apologize for not knowing it earlier. English is not my first language.) But what should be done for questions such as these?

Comment: related meta: ["How do I reference a racially charged term..."](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11238/23970)

Comment: In this case, the term seems sort of essential to the question because it's a specific game term in that edition – albeit one that has been removed from later editions.

Comment: English is my first language and I didn't know that was a term at all, much less a slur, until I looked it up because of your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Same as we do with questions that include any other word on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_slurs):

Recognize that that many words have different meanings in different contexts. If you're using a word as a slur, don't. Do something different instead. If you are using a word that is sometimes a slur, avoid using it in a way that may cause confusion about how you mean it.

For example, "orc" has seen recent use as a slur* against Russians. We do not need to endorse that usage to continue answering question about orcs in the context of fantasy games.

This is distinct from the [linked question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11238/25662), which asks about a slur used as a slur (albeit with a more complicated intent).

*Regardless of any other context or provocations, it's clearly an ethnic slur.